# How to write it better way e.g. lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to check every child on way in array
can i write it better with e.g. lodash

```
test[1] && test[1][2] && test[1][2][3] && doSomething
```

Comment: Can you show an example of that array by editing the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 common ways to get/check paths with lodash:

1. _.[**get**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) - which would attempt to get the value based on path and provide `default` if that value is not found
2. _.[**has**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#has) - which would give you boolean result if the path is found or not
   _.[**hasIn**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#hasIn) - which is like has but also would check if path is a direct or inherited property of object
3. _.[**result**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#result) - which would walk the path and execute **any** function among the way to get to the value or work as `_.get` otherwise (no functions present)

```js
var data = [
        [],
        [
          [],
          [
           'hello',
    function(){ return 'foo'}
          ]
        ]
    ];
  
console.log('get:', _.get(data, '1.1.0'))
console.log('has:', _.has(data, '1.1.0'))

console.log('result:', _.result(data, '1.1.0'))
console.log('result:', _.result(data, '1.1.1'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The common thing here is all of them accept a `path` as a parameter which can do what you want. Just provide the `deepest` path and let those methods check/work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could check with [`_.has(object, path)`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#has)

> Checks if `path` is a direct property of `object`.

```
_.has(test, '[1][2][3]') && doSomething;
```

or

```
_.has(test, [1, 2, 3]) && doSomething;
```

If you like to get the value, then take [`_.get(object, path, [default])`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get)

```js
var test = [
        [],
        [
            [],
            [],
            [
                [], [], [], 42
            ]
        ]
    ];

console.log(test[1][2][3]);
console.log(_.has(test, '[1][2][3]'));
console.log(_.has(test, [1, 2, 3]));

console.log(_.has(test, '[1][2][30]'));
console.log(_.has(test, [1, 2, 30]));

console.log(_.get(test, '[1][2][3]'));
console.log(_.get(test, [1, 2, 3]));

console.log(_.get(test, '[1][2][30]'));
console.log(_.get(test, [1, 2, 30]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It looks like the OP's array is nested at least three levels. Will `has` still work with that?

Answer (score 0):

with `_.get` you can get value in path or return default value:

```
_.get(test, [1, 2, 3], doSomething);
```